# ACM Jolly jumper

Tags: c++

I have problem with this question I do not know why I always get WA my code is right and work without problem I dont know where is the problem I test it in several test case but it worked

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    vector <int> num;

    int n,temp,j=0;

    cin>>n;

    for(int i= 0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        cin>>temp;

        num.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<num.size() ; i++)
    {

        if(i+1 < num.size())
        {
            j++;

            if(abs(num[i] - num[i+1]) != (n-j) && abs(num[i] - num[i+1]) !=(j))
            {
                cout<<"Not jolly"<<endl;

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"Jolly"<<endl;

}
```

Comment: It might help to describe what your code is supposed to do, what `WA` means, and so on--i.e., enough information that somebody other than you can actually figure out what it means and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry WA is Wrong Answer!!!                                                                      And that is problem    :                                                     A sequence of n > 0 integers is called a jolly jumper if the absolute values of the difference between successive elements take on all the values 1 through n-1. For instance,
1 4 2 3
is a jolly jumper, because the absolutes differences are 3, 2, and 1 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understood the problem incorrectly. Quoting from the [problem statement](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=979):

> A sequence of n > 0 integers is called a jolly jumper if the absolute values of the difference between successive elements take on all the values 1 through n-1.

Therefore: `2 5 1 3 4` is also a jolly sequence for `N = 5`. However, your program outputs that it isn't.

If you solve the task from [Uva online judge](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/), then may have one more problem - you read the input only once, whereas in Uva it is written that:

> Each line of input contains an integer n <= 3000 followed by n integers representing the sequence.

Comment: @Danial No, it means that the absolute differences between every two consecutive numbers should be a permutation (every number from 1 to N-1 appears exactly one time in it) of the numbers from 1 to N-1. So for example in `2 5 1 3 4` (with N = 5) those differences are `|2-5| = 3`, `|5-1| = 4`, `|1-3| = 2` and `|3-4| = 1`, or in other words, the permutation 3 4 2 1. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your account details - Click here
Code on the Go
menu
GUVI : Learn to code in your native language

Advanced DS - KPR1
Share
A common but insecure method of encrypting text is to permute the letters of the alphabet. In other words, each letter of the alphabet is consistently replaced in the text by some other letter. To ensure that the encryption is reversible, no two letters are replaced by the same letter. Your task is to decrypt several encoded lines of text, assuming that each line uses a different set of replacements, and that all words in the decrypted text are from a dictionary of known words.

Input Description:
The input consists of a line containing an integer n, followed by n lowercase words, one per line, in alphabetical order. These n words compose the dictionary of words which may appear in the decrypted text. Following the dictionary are several lines of input. Each line is encrypted as described above. There are no more than 1,000 words in the dictionary. No word exceeds 16 letters. The encrypted lines contain only lower case letters and spaces and do not exceed 80 characters in length.

Output Description:
Decrypt each line and print it to standard output. If there are multiple solutions, any one will do. If there is no solution, replace every letter of the alphabet by an asterisk.

Sample Input :
6
and
kick
jane
puff
spot
yertle
gjvg xsb hxsn xsb qymm xsb rqat xsb pnetfn
xxxx yyy zzzz www yyyy aaa bbbb ccc dddddd
Sample Output :
kick and jane and puff and spot and yertle

---

Code Editor

Input
Output
Enter Your Input